# Mock Java implementation of an intermediate throw event in Camunda

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I would like to mock the Java implementation for an intermediate throw event until it is implemented later on. However, I do not know what method I have to use when I want to mock it through a Java Class. I only know that for a service task, I can use

```
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Java Class is called! - not yet implemented!");
}
```

Can I use this method for an intermediate throw event as well and specify the Java class name in the properties of the throw event in the BPMN diagram?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Implement `org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate` and configure the class. In BPMN XML it looks like this:

```
<intermediateThrowEvent id="message">
  <messageEventDefinition camunda:class="org.camunda.bpm.MyMessageServiceDelegate" />
</intermediateThrowEvent>
```

See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/#message-intermediate-throwing-event